# How to run GPS based application (WikiTude) in Android SDK Emulator?

Tags: android, gps, emulation

I am writing an Android application which uses WikiTude API. I installed the WikiTude browser application in the Android SDK emulator from Android Market (To get Android Market in emulator I followed this link http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-529170.html).

When I run the WikiTude browser application in emulator it asks me to set location settings. I enabled “Enable GPS satellites” option & run the application, again it make an alert for location settings. I am not able to run this application. Please help me.

Can anyone tell me is it possible to run GPS based application in Android Emulator? Or not?
                          If it is, Is there any work around to run GPS based application in emulator ?

Comment: I love how it decided to highlight the code block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you can simulate GPS location changes in the emulator, via the Location Controls in DDMS perspective - you can set up these location updates manually, or you can load [GPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_eXchange_Format) or [KML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) data.

A little longer answer: Depending on the type of location data you need for your application, you can find the emulator not exactly thrilling in terms of simulation capabilities. Also it's always good to test battery-expensive applications on real devices, because Android devices (at least most of them) are first and foremost mobile phones/netbooks and most of the times you would prefer to sacrifice some accuracy in exchange for battery life.
Still, if you want to try the GPS simulation (which is perfectly fine for simpler testing), take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html#emulator-control) or in one of the better books about Android (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114287/good-book-for-beginning-android-development and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949818/how-can-i-learn-android should help)

Comment: Also, many GPS-dependent libraries also use the Google APIs, so make sure the AVD emulator image you created contains those and not just the core Android system libraries.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you send coordinates to an emulator instance they don't contain accuracy information.